# Angular using javascript to make sort Pipe

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, pipe

I have a question when I build sort pipe in Angular2
here is my pipe code:

[image]

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'sort'
})
export class SortPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, propName: string): any {

    return value.sort((a,b)=> {
      return a[propName]-b[propName];
      // if(a[propName]>b[propName]) {
      //   return 1;
      // } else {
      //   return -1;
      // }
    });        
  }      
}
```

When I use the code in comments, the pipe works, but when I use return a `[propName]-b[propName];` it is not working;

Comment: chances are, youre trying to subtract a string from a string by the looks if it

Comment: And have you seen this: https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe It highly recommends against building pipes that sort or filter. Do it in your component class instead. I have an example of a filter here: https://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/filtering-in-angular/ You could do something similar for the sort.

Comment: @DeborahK that recommendation provides no evidence. I have used such pipes in multiple production apps without issue.

Answer (score 1):

For sort to work, you must return an integer ([see reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/Array/sort)). Are you sure, that subtracting your properties will always return these values?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I want to try this because I saw https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_array_sort2

Comment: @Mia I edited my answer to reflect an error I have made. You can subtract numbers, but your answer also has to be a number. So you must be sure, that every object has this param (you cannot subtract undefined), and return value can be casted to number (for example `5 - null` will yield `5`, but `5 - 'st'` will yield `NaN`).

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you are sorting. If the value is a number it should work. If it's a string then a NaN is returned. Second solution is better.

Answer (score -1):

This code selects the property of the list of **items** objects passed in by the pipe and takes into consideration null values.

Below you can see what the pipe will look like with the *ngFor:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of Clients | sort: sortType: sortDirection">
```

Below you can see when the column header is clicked, the arrows change direction of the arrow and make the sort output ascending or descending within the sort pipe.

```
<th>
        <div class="d-flex flex-row hoverOver">
          <span class="text-nowrap">Quantity</span>
          <i class="fa hoverTrans align-self-center mx-1" [ngClass]="{'fa-arrows-v': column != 'created',
            'fas fa-long-arrow-up': !sortDirection,
            'fas fa-long-arrow-down': sortDirection }" (click)="sortType = 'qty'; sortDirection = !sortDirection">
          </i>
```

Below is the Sort Pipe:

```
transform(items: any, sortType: any, sortDirection: any): any {

    const direction = sortDirection ? -1 : 1;

    items.sort((a, b) => {
      if (a[sortType] < b[sortType] || (a[sortType] === null && b[sortType] !== null) || (a[sortType] === "" && b[sortType] !== null)) {
        return -1 * direction;
      } else if (a[sortType] > b[sortType] || (a[sortType] !== null && b[sortType] === null) || (a[sortType] !== null && b[sortType] === "")) {
        return 1 * direction;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    });

    return items;
  }
```

Comment: Don't use images, instead write the code in code blocks. Is more readable

Comment: Thanks for the feedback I have updated my answer for readability.